# Trouble decoding data

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

I'm having trouble decoding this string using python:

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\r\t\n\x0b\n\x08\r\x0b....
```

I'm curious what type of encoding this is. Thanks!

Comment: ok thanks, do you memorize these patterns, or is there some site that tells you common encryption patterns?

Comment: Ok, well what I mean to say is can you tell the format of a file just by looking at the first couple characters?

Answer (score 3):

You can store this header in a file using Python as below:

```
>>> data =  b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\r\t\n\x0b\n\x08\r\x0b'
>>> data
'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\r\t\n\x0b\n\x08\r\x0b'
>>> f = open("d:\\testFile.txt", "wb")
>>> f.write(data)
>>> f.close()
>>>
```

And then using `file` command in Linux distribution, you can find out with type of file you have:

[image]

Comment: how to convert this data back  to Image ?